# Img src change on page load

Tags: javascript, image, onload

I want JavaScript to load a few img src's on page load. However my solution doesn't seem to work.
Any help would be very appreciated.

HTML

```
<li><img id="option1" height="45px" width="75px" alt="" src=""></li>
<li><img id="option2" height="45px" width="75px" alt="" src=""></li>
```

JavaScript

```
function filltopfoto(){
    var settoppic = new Image;
    for (var i = 0; i <= itemlist;i++){
        settoppic.src = 'img' + i + '.jpg';
        $('option' + i).src = settoppic.src;
    }
}
```

FYI: 
itemlist contains the amount of images that need to be filled.
The script gets loaded on body load.

Comment: I don't quite understand why; image tags don't block page loading so you gain nothing by loading them immediately on body load.

Comment: i dont quite understand if youre using jquery

Comment: your loop sets <img> to last image in the loop every time that you reload page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNpNB/1/) of the code below to show a real example.

```
images = ["image1/url", "image2/url"]              // define image source urls

$(document).ready(function(){                      // wait until the document is ready
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)         // loop over all images
        $('#option'+(i+1)).attr('src', images[i]); // set the src attribute, note the '#'
});
```

A couple of your mistakes:

1. JQuery's `$('#id')` look-up requires the hashtag (#) for ids.
2. Your `filltopfoto()` function is never called (Try doing `alert('hello!')` inside the function).
3. Your `$('options'+i)` gives `options0` and `options`1 -- you need `options1` and `options2`
4. Not sure why you create a `new Image` just to store a `src` variable. You can remove this code.

Comment: The code was called however putting an image in the img src didn't work .And i also messed up with the location of the images because i thought it started looking from the js's file location while it actually started from the html location .Here's the code after changing it.(this way adding pics is automatic)
`var itemlist = $('#IStopoptions > li').size();>
function filltopfoto(){
 var settoppic = new Image;
 for (var i = 0; i <= itemlist;i++){
  settoppic.src = 'js/imggallery/img' + i + '.jpg';
  $('#option' + i).attr('src', 'js/imggallery/img' + i + '.jpg');
 }
}`